# setting up admin views with flask + admin module

Tags: python, flask

In the following code, everything defaults over to the Member's index controller. How can I setup add_view to point to particular methods within Members? This way I can have a single Members button with functionality related to it in the dropdown.

views:

```
admin.add_view(Members(name="Add",endpoint="add",category="Members"))
admin.add_view(Members(name="Edit",endpoint="edit",category="Members"))
admin.add_view
(Members(name="Delete",endpoint="delete",category="Members"))
```

admin module:

```
from flask import render_template, abort
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound
from flask.ext.admin import BaseView, expose, Admin

admin = Admin(name='Foo')

# Add administrative views here

class Members(BaseView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        return self.render('admin/index.html')

    @expose('/edit')
    def edit(self):
        return self.render('admin/edit.html')

    @expose('/delete')
    def delete(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how it'll help, as you're creating 3 instances of same class. While you can keep implementation highly coupled, it won't be as different as having 3 different classes.

Anyway, `add_view` will always point menu item to `index` method. However, `self._default_view` contains default view method name (index for your `Members` class).

Just to give an idea how it can look like:

```
class MyBase(BaseView):
  def __init__(self, def_view, **kwargs):
    self._default_view = def_view
    super(MyBase, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Members(MyBase):
  @expose('/')
  def index(self):
    return self.render('...')

  #.. other view methods

admin.add_view(Members(def_view='index', name='Add', endpoint='add'))
admin.add_view(Members(def_view='edit', name='Edit', endpoint='edit'))
# ...
```

Comment: I don't really understand this answer. I have the same problem as the OP. Based on the docs, the apparent purpose of defining different methods within the custom class is to allow the developer to add them as separately rendered endpoints which are presented within a dropdown.  When you say "add_view always points to the index method"  then I don't understand the point of defining different methods/endpoints.  The examples are not of much help in this regard

Comment: I tried the pattern above, but it duplicated the endpoint names, ie. admin/edit/edit.  I ended up just creating different view classes, and using add_view on each of them to get them into the dropdown.